# Checking by not restricting how many elements

Tags: javascript

I want to make it like for example when the word spilt into elements, the checking part will not restrict to only four.(In code comment it as "this part"). I want to be depending on how many the elements split so that it will be correct.

```
 if(original[0]==$("#box1").text()&&original[1]==$("#box2").text()&&original[2]==$("#box3").text()&&original[3]==$("#box4").text())
```

This only restricted to four, then the checking will be correct. How can I do it such as there will be three split elements or more then four elements and the checking will still be correct.

```
<script>
js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";
var c = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','c10'];
var div_id = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10'];
var box_id = ['box1','box2','box3','box4','box5','box6','box7','box8','box9','box10'];
var original = js_var.split("#");
var balls90= js_var.split("#");


var x = document.getElementById("demo");
for (var i=0; i < original.length; i++) {
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = c[i];
el.innerHTML = original[i];
x.appendChild(el);
}


function getNumbers() {
var player1 = new Array();
balls90.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - .25;
    document.getElementById("shuffle").onclick = function(){displayDate()};
});

 for (var i = 0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
     document.writeln('<div id='+box_id[i]+' class=box droppable=true ondrop=drop(event)     
ondragover=allowDrop(event)></div>');
 }


for (var i = 0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
    player1.push(balls90[i]);


    document.writeln('<div id='+div_id[i]+' draggable=true droppable=true 
ondragstart=drag(event)>'+balls90[i]+'</div>');

 }

}

getNumbers();


function dragWord(dragEvent){
dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/html",     
dragEvent.target.textContent+"|"+dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
}


function dropWord(dropEvent){
var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
var dropItems = dropData.split("|");
var prevElem = document.getElementById(dropItems[1]);
prevElem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent = dropEvent.target.textContent;
dropEvent.target.textContent = dropItems[0];
dropEvent.preventDefault();
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}  


function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

 //this part

if(original[0]==$("#box1").text()&&original[1]==$("#box2").text()&&original[2]==$("#box3").text()&&original[3]==$("#box4").text())
    {
        alert('correct');
    }

}
<script>
```

Comment: Create a loop over `original`?

Comment: @PM 77-1 May I know how?

Comment: Posted. This is untested.  Just to give an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
var result = true;
for (var i=0, i<original.length, ++i) {
   if (original[i] !== $("#box"+(i+1)).text()) {
     result = false;
     break;
   }
}

if(result) {
    alert('correct');
}
```

Comment: I ussed this but this still restrict to 4. May I know how to do?                                                           for(var i=0;i<original.length;++i){
if (original[i] == $("#box"+(i+1)).text()) {
         match++;
         console.log('match'+match);
       }
    }
   
   if(match==4) {
       alert('correct');
   }

Comment: It will process **all** elements (or until the first not matching) of `original` array.  What is the **size** of this array in your code?

Comment: The size of original is depending on how many elements it is break into.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. What test?

Comment: You said that ran my code and still got 4.  At that time what was the size of the array?

Comment: 4. Because the sentence is break up into 4 elements. For example, I like to read. So it have four element each "I", "like", "to", "read.". Then the code now Is  if(match==4) so it only restricted to 4 right so it will be correct when checking. What I want is there is no restricted, it can be 4,7 or even 3. How can I do that?

Comment: So try a sentence with 4, 7, or 3 words.  My code will follow the length of the array.

Comment: You said: "*I want to be depending on how many the elements split so that it will be correct.*" That what I did. It will process **as many elements as there are in the array**.  If there are 4 elements, it will process 4. If you meant something else then clarify your requirements.